# Do PHP session use cookie internally ? What is session cookie?

Tags: php, session, cookies

I have not written any code to set or get cookie. Am using only PHP session.

Its a mobile application and runs on Windows CE and Windows mobile scanners

If i don't accept cookie session will not work.

It specifically say accept session cookie. When i accept it works.

So what is this Session Cookie ? any one have any idea

I think it is specifically to mobile scanners !!

Comment: A session cookie stores the session ID which is required to identify the current session.

Comment: But strange things i ....Even if i block all coookies it works fine from desktop pc IE , but will not work in mobile scanner if i dont accept cookie

Comment: Did you read the documentation on sessions in the PHP manual?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes PHP sessions use cookies

(You can [propogate the session id via the URL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.use-trans-sid) however this is famously insecure and will break anywhere PHP has difficulty parsing the URL (e.g. within javascript). Until such time as you really understand how sessions work in HTTP and PHP, then I'd strongly advise you to stick with cookie based sessions)

> So what is this Session Cookie

In this context it has a dual meaning: firstly it contains a value which references a set of data stored on the server- the session data. Secondly, they are usually implemented as browser session cookies - i.e. they persist on the browser as long as the browser is running, no longer.

> I think it is specifically to mobile scanners !!

No.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, PHP sessions use cookies. If you don't accept the cookie, PHP has no way to keep track of what session your request is a part of.

Comment: hmm.. I thought that if you didn't accept cookies, PHP would (or could anyways) rewrite your URLs to include a PHPSESSID parameter.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.use-cookies. You don't *have* to configure PHP to use cookies with sessions.

Comment: @Eric not anymore by default. You have to enable that. Reason is security risk.

Comment: But strange things i ....Even if i block all coookies it works fine from desktop pc IE , but will not work in mobile scanner if i dont accept cookie

Comment: If it's working on a desktop, you aren't actually blocking the cookies.